# Binding and events to control scrollbar

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a frame/canvas, controlled with horizontal and vertical scrollbars.
I bind the pressed left mouse button.

```
bind $canvas <ButtonPress-1>   [list start $canvas]
bind $canvas <ButtonRelease-1> stop
```

This "grabs" the canvas to move it during pressed mouse.

I tried to control using

```
proc start {c} {
  move
}
proc move {} {
 .<MISSING IDEE>....
 after 10 move
}
proc stop {} {
  after cancel move
}
```

My question is now. What can be the glue between the canvas and and the scrollbars, to control xscroll and yscroll by moving the pressed mouse pointer. Is there trick or do I have do deal with positions in both canvas and scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

### Synchronizing the canvas and scrollbars

The "glue" is the configuration options which tie the scrollbars to the canvas and visa versa. This is a two step process: configure the canvas to know what it's scrollbars are, and configure the scrollbars to know what they are scrolling.

First, a canvas must be told what scrollbar to update in the horizontal and vertical dimensions. For example, let's assume your scrollbars are identified as `$vsb` and `$hsb`. You would configure the canvas like this:

```
$canvas configure -xscrollcommand [list $hsb set] -yscrollcommand [list $vsb set]
```

With the above, whenever the scrollable area changes in size or the canvas is scrolled -- no matter how -- the scrollbars will be updated to reflect the current view.

Next, you must perform a similar step for the scrollbars. In this case the option is `-command`, which tells the scrollbar what command to run when the scrollbar is moved. All scrollable widgets provide a command that can be called to adjust the view of the widget.

For example:

```
$vsb configure -command [list $canvas yview]
$hsb configure -command [list $canvas xview]
```

### Programmatically scrolling the canvas

To programmatically scroll the canvas in your `move` function, you just need to do the same thing that the scrollbar does: call the `xview` and/or `yview` commands. These commands take additional arguments to know how much to scroll and in what direction.

For example, to simulate dragging the horizontal scrollbar to the right one pixel you would do this:

```
$canvas xview scroll 1 units
```

When you call that function it will behave precisely as if you had dragged the scrollbar.

For more information, see the documentation on the [xview](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M78) and [yview](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M82) canvas commands.

### Using the built-in features of the canvas

If your goal is to scroll the canvas with the mouse, you can do away with almost all of your code and replace it with calls to the [scan](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M68) command provided by the canvas.

For example:

```
bind $canvas <ButtonPress-1> {%W scan mark %x %y}
bind $canvas <B1-Motion> {%W scan dragto %x %y 1}
```